# `push.js` no se ejecuta dentro de forEach

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, push.js

Quiero que si mi `forEach` tenga **n iteraciones** salgan **n notificaciones**. En este caso, no se ejecuta ninguna notificación. Si saco la creación de la notificación del `forEach`, se ejecuta correctamente.

```js
$.ajax({  
  async:    true,  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "mensajes.php",  
  data: "",  
  dataType:"json",  
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);

    data.forEach(function(item) { 
      console.log("jalo");
      Push.create("Hola desde la bd", {
        body: "Este es el cuerpo de la notificacion",
        icon: "watson.jpg",
        timeout: 4000,

        onClick: function () {
          alert("notificación");
          this.close();
        }

      });
    }); 

    // $.ajax({
    //  async:  true, 
    //  type: "POST",
    //  url: "actualizar.php",
    //  data: "",
    //  dataType:"html",
    //  success: function(data) {   

      // }
    // });
  }
});
```

Json:

```
[
   {
      "id":"53",
      "mensaje":"asdasd",
      "timestamp":"2020-01-22 17:30:36",
      "status":"1",
      "tipo":"1",
      "notificacion":"0"
   },
   {
      "id":"54",
      "mensaje":"asds",
      "timestamp":"2020-01-22 17:30:44",
      "status":"1",
      "tipo":"2",
      "notificacion":"0"
   },
   {
      "id":"55",
      "mensaje":"asdasd",
      "timestamp":"2020-01-22 17:34:15",
      "status":"1",
      "tipo":"2",
      "notificacion":"0"
   },
   {
      "id":"56",
      "mensaje":"asds",
      "timestamp":"2020-01-22 17:36:17",
      "status":"1",
      "tipo":"1",
      "notificacion":"0"
   },
   {
      "id":"57",
      "mensaje":"notifiacion 1",
      "timestamp":"2020-01-22 17:36:42",
      "status":"1",
      "tipo":"2",
      "notificacion":"0"
   },
   {
      "id":"58",
      "mensaje":"asdasd",
      "timestamp":"2020-01-22 17:38:12",
      "status":"1",
      "tipo":"2",
      "notificacion":"0"
   }
]
```

Comment: ¿Qué es Push.create? ¿Es una librería? ¿Una función creada por ti? ¿Qué valor tiene el valor data?

Comment: Buen día @FernandoTorres push.create es parte de la libreria push.js, data por su parte tiene un json de n arreglos.

Comment: Muy bien, Carlos, y bienvenido. ¿Podrías poner el json que te retorna tu Push.js?

Comment: @FernandoTorres Lo puse, solo que, en realidad no lo utilizo mas que para los ciclos, me di cuenta que si mi foreach solo tiene 1 arreglo, push.js se ejecuta correctamente, el problema esta cuando es 2 o mas iteraciones, osea que tenga que crear mas de 1 notificación, lo mismo si meto la creación de la notifiación en otro tipo de ciclo, no se si la librería tiene alguna restricción

Comment: Ok, Carlos, siento que estás creando tantas alertas que javascript las prologan en cada iteración que haces, por eso cada vez tarda más tiempo en aparecer esta alerta al punto que nunca lo ves aparecer. Lo que yo te recomiendo es meter ese código en un callback para que cuando termine el primer alert, siga con el siguiente, algo así como recursivo, saludos.

Comment: gracias @FernandoTorres, lo que hice para solucionar esto, fue cambiar la lógica de mi código, el escuchador que tengo para las notificaciones trae 1 por 1 y esa la actualiza como ya mostrada y así sucesivamente, en vez de traerme todas las que están activas, la verdad no verifique si es posible con el callback.